# defer attribute for a file that is already on the bottom

Tags: javascript, html

Since the browser read the file from top to bottom what is the point of using the defer attribute if the js file is at the bottom ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>some title</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <h1>hello world</h1>
    <img src=">
    <script defer src="defer-script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

shouldn't the web browser by default load parse the h1 and the image before parsing the script ? what is the point of the defer attr in this example or how exactly the browser will parse the html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accordint to documentation

> Scripts with the defer attribute will prevent the DOMContentLoaded
> event from firing until the script has loaded and finished evaluating.
>
> The defer attribute has no effect on module scripts — they defer by
> default.
>
> Scripts with the defer attribute will execute in the order in which
> they appear in the document.

So parsing will be with the next logic

The defer attribute tells the browser not to wait for the script. Instead, the browser will continue to process the HTML, build DOM. The script loads “in the background”, and then runs when the DOM is fully built.